# Nuxt.js - preload шрифтов в production

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, http2

При разработке все отлично, но при сборке production в preload не попадают шрифты. Есть все, кроме шрифтов.

```
render: {
    http2: {
        push: true,
        pushAssets: (req, res, publicPath, preloadFiles) => console.log(preloadFiles)
    }
}
```

Вывод в dev (`nuxt`)

```
[                                                                                                                                                                 05:38:10
  {
    file: 'runtime.js',
    extension: 'js',
    fileWithoutQuery: 'runtime.js',
    asType: 'script'
  },
  {
    file: 'vendors.app.js',
    extension: 'js',
    fileWithoutQuery: 'vendors.app.js',
    asType: 'script'
  },
  {
    file: 'app.js',
    extension: 'js',
    fileWithoutQuery: 'app.js',
    asType: 'script'
  },
  {
    file: 'assets/fonts/Play.woff',
    extension: 'woff',
    fileWithoutQuery: 'assets/fonts/Play.woff',
    asType: 'font'
  },
  {
    file: 'assets/fonts/Play.woff2',
    extension: 'woff2',
    fileWithoutQuery: 'assets/fonts/Play.woff2',
    asType: 'font'
  },
  {
    file: 'assets/fonts/PlayBold.woff',
    extension: 'woff',
    fileWithoutQuery: 'assets/fonts/PlayBold.woff',
    asType: 'font'
  },
  {
    file: 'assets/fonts/PlayBold.woff2',
    extension: 'woff2',
    fileWithoutQuery: 'assets/fonts/PlayBold.woff2',
    asType: 'font'
  },
  {
    file: 'pages/index.js',
    extension: 'js',
    fileWithoutQuery: 'pages/index.js',
    asType: 'script'
  },
  {
    file: 'assets/images/logo.svg',
    extension: 'svg',
    fileWithoutQuery: 'assets/images/logo.svg',
    asType: 'image'
  },
  {
    file: 'pages/check.html.pages/index.js',
    extension: 'js',
    fileWithoutQuery: 'pages/check.html.pages/index.js',
    asType: 'script'
  },
  {
    file: 'pages/chatbot.html.pages/check.html.pages/checker.html.pages/en.html.pages/index.pages/promo.html.pa.eb68a2f3.js',
    extension: 'js',
    fileWithoutQuery: 'pages/chatbot.html.pages/check.html.pages/checker.html.pages/en.html.pages/index.pages/promo.html.pa.eb68a2f3.js',
    asType: 'script'
  },
  {
    file: 'assets/images/rocket.svg',
    extension: 'svg',
    fileWithoutQuery: 'assets/images/rocket.svg',
    asType: 'image'
  },
  {
    file: 'pages/chatbot.html.pages/checker.html.pages/en.html.pages/index.pages/vkim.html.js',
    extension: 'js',
    fileWithoutQuery: 'pages/chatbot.html.pages/checker.html.pages/en.html.pages/index.pages/vkim.html.js',
    asType: 'script'
  },
  {
    file: 'assets/images/orbit.svg',
    extension: 'svg',
    fileWithoutQuery: 'assets/images/orbit.svg',
    asType: 'image'
  }
]
```

Вывод в production (`nuxt build; nuxt start`):

```
[                                                                                                                                                                 05:35:15
  {
    file: '5e0bcb963558b2151b59.js',
    extension: 'js',
    fileWithoutQuery: '5e0bcb963558b2151b59.js',
    asType: 'script'
  },
  {
    file: 'a8df7e6ca1b41b6ba1f3.js',
    extension: 'js',
    fileWithoutQuery: 'a8df7e6ca1b41b6ba1f3.js',
    asType: 'script'
  },
  {
    file: 'da6509a7baaff1386039.js',
    extension: 'js',
    fileWithoutQuery: 'da6509a7baaff1386039.js',
    asType: 'script'
  },
  {
    file: '834b4e9b65d7391ff800.js',
    extension: 'js',
    fileWithoutQuery: '834b4e9b65d7391ff800.js',
    asType: 'script'
  },
  {
    file: 'img/0b5b752.svg',
    extension: 'svg',
    fileWithoutQuery: 'img/0b5b752.svg',
    asType: 'image'
  },
  {
    file: 'img/d2dc191.svg',
    extension: 'svg',
    fileWithoutQuery: 'img/d2dc191.svg',
    asType: 'image'
  },
  {
    file: '54f9bec00b4174f52059.js',
    extension: 'js',
    fileWithoutQuery: '54f9bec00b4174f52059.js',
    asType: 'script'
  },
  {
    file: 'img/5ad4226.svg',
    extension: 'svg',
    fileWithoutQuery: 'img/5ad4226.svg',
    asType: 'image'
  }
]
```

Comment: Пробовали [вот этот совет](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/1508#issuecomment-325655533)? Цитата из [документации к этой опции](https://ssr.vuejs.org/api/#shouldpreload): "By default, only JavaScript and CSS files will be preloaded, as they are absolutely needed for your application to boot.

For other types of assets such as images or fonts, preloading too much may waste bandwidth and even hurt performance, so what to preload will be scenario-dependent. You can control precisely what to preload using the shouldPreload option"

Comment: Пробовал. `shouldPreload` влияет только на `<link rel="preload">`, на заголовки http не влияет. И даже там в production не попадают шрифты, так же консолил

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ был получен в https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55348119/nuxt-js-fonts-preload-in-production

---

Это баг в vue/nuxt.

PR с исправлением -> https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/pull/5436

PR в vue -> https://github.com/vuejs/vue/pull/9802